# Downloading an image from a URL ending in .png

Tags: google-chrome

I am attempting to download multiple images by URL
using the Chrome extension `Bulk URL Opener`.

```
http://charas-project.net/resources_download.php?id=38043&file=resources%2FCharasets%2F51168_1293717592.PNG
http://charas-project.net/resources_download.php?id=38052&file=resources%2FCharasets%2F51949_1294895391.png
http://charas-project.net/resources_download.php?id=38056&file=resources%2FCharasets%2F51949_1294895993.png
http://charas-project.net/resources_download.php?id=38057&file=resources%2FCharasets%2F51949_1294896045.png
http://charas-project.net/resources_download.php?id=38058&file=resources%2FCharasets%2F51949_1294896097.png
```

Chrome opens these URLs and I have to right click on image and save the images separately.

What I want is for Chrome to download the images automatically without having to right click on image and save as.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't `wget` or `curl` or some other command line tool be more appropriate to download a list of files?

Comment: You shouldn't enable any feature or add-ons that can download file automatically. Any file may be malicious. Use any download tool like as Mokubai says, `wget`, `curl`, `aria2c`, `w3m` etc.

Comment: Is there possibly an app that can do this on mac computer?